# Variable is undefined error when passing argument to Ansible roles

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I am new to ansible roles here is what i am doing.

more site.yml

```
---

- hosts: user1_checkserverlist
  user: user1
  roles:
    - { role: speed_manager, DNAME: "/u" }

- hosts: oracle_checkserverlist
  user: oracle
  roles:
    - { role: speed_manager, DNAME: "/tmp" }
```

more speed_manager/defaults/main.yml

```
DNAME: ""
```

more speed_manager/tasks/main.yml

```
---

- include: check.yml diskname={{DNAME}}
```

more speed_manager/tasks/check.yml

```
---

   - name: ==== Reading Variable ====
     ping:
     vars:
         dn: "{{ diskname }}"

   - name: ====Sync  to remote hosts ====

     synchronize: src="/web/roles/speed_manager/files/" dest="/tmp/mohtt/"

   - name: ====Execute shell=============

     shell: /tmp/mohtt/fixwebserver.sh {{ dn }} chdir=/tmp/mohtt
```

This is how i execute the roles

```
ansible-playbook -vvv site.yml -i /web/hostfiles/myhost.txt
```

Error:

> ```
> TASK [check_bk_speed_manager : ====Execute shell=============] *****************
> task path: /web/roles/speed_manager/tasks/check.yml:25
> fatal: [myserver.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dn' is undefined"}
> fatal: [myserver.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dn' is undefined"}
>         to retry, use: --limit @check_bk_speed.retry
> ```

I was expecting the value of dn to be "/u"

Can you point out where am i going wrong and if this is a bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to use a different name for the variable that you already have defined.

You can change your tasks to use `diskname`, which you pass in the `include` task:

```
- name: ====Execute shell=============
  shell: /tmp/mohtt/fixwebserver.sh {{ diskname }} chdir=/tmp/mohtt
```

---

Actually, if this is the whole code, you can go with `DNAME`:

```
- name: ====Execute shell=============
  shell: /tmp/mohtt/fixwebserver.sh {{ DNAME }} chdir=/tmp/mohtt
```

And include with just:

```
- include: check.yml
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example you define `dn` only for task *"Reading Variable"*.
Other tasks know nothing about `dn`.

If you want `dn` to be available for subsequent tasks, you can use:

```
- set_fact:
    dn: "{{ diskname }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In `speed_manager/tasks/check.yml` instead of `dn` use `diskname` as the variable 
or in the beginning of the file add

```
- set_fact:
  dn: "{{ diskname }}"
```